# can't call a public method in a class inside of a main class after creating an instance of the class

Tags: java

I feel like this is a noobish question but I'm getting back into java so I'm a little stumped

I have a Player class that contains a public attack method() but for some reason when I try to call the method in the main class where I have created an instance of the Player class java says it can't find the method? I'm hoping someone can tell me what's wrong

I have tried rebuilding the class to make sure it was up to date... I don't see any other errors with other methods in the class.. so I'm not sure what the issue is??

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.example.Player.attack()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:2227)
    at org.example.Main.main(Main.java:31)
```

here is my player class

```
package org.example;
import java.util.Random;


public class Player {
    public String name;
    public static int health;
    public int def;
    public int atk;
    private String[] domains = {"hauntings","findings","solutions","busters","slayers","defense","protection","powers","scary"};

    public Player(String name, int health, int atk, int def) {
        this.name = name;
        this.health = health;
        this.atk = atk;
        this.def = def;
    }

    // player will make an http request for a random site trying to find anything related to ghosts
    // if the response is 200 we assume the player has learned something new about ghosts and increased their knowledge
    // this in turn increases player atk power

    public void loseHealth(int amount){
        this.health = this.health-amount;
        System.out.println(this.name+" now has "+this.health+" health");
    }
   public void searchWebForAnswers () {
       Random random = new Random();
        int randomIndex = random.nextInt(this.domains.length);
        String randomUrl = domains[randomIndex];

        // if this website exists we will increase atk by 1
        if( randomUrl == "defense"){
            this.atk +=1;
        }
    }

    public void attack(Ghost ghost){
        Random rand = new Random();
        double attackPlusRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() *(4-1 +this.atk) + 1);
        if(this.atk > ghost.def && ghost.getIsTransparent() == false){
            ghost.setGhostHealth(this.atk-ghost.def);
        }else{
            System.out.println("the attack does no damage: player_atk:"+this.atk+"ghost_defense:"+ghost.def);
        }
    }

    public int getHealth(){
        return this.health;
    }
    public void setPlayerHealth(int val){
        this.health = val;
    }
}
```

here is my main class

```
package org.example;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException {
        String[] playerMethods = {"attack", "searchWebForAnswers"};
        String[] ghostMethods = {"learnToSpeak", "sayBoo", "haunt","becomeTransparent","attack"};
        System.out.println("BEGIN THE HAUNT!");

        /*
         player will go first, then ghost
         a random action will be taken by whoever goes
         the turns continue until either the ghost is exorcised or the player dies
         */

        Player player = new Player("Luther", 10, 1, 3);
        Ghost ghost = new Ghost(20, 0, 3);

            while (player.health > 0 && ghost.health > 0) {
                Random random = new Random();

                // a random method is chosen each turn
                // this does not include methods like getHealth or methods used by the game to determine state

                    System.out.println("player is taking their turn");
                    int randomMethodIndex = random.nextInt(playerMethods.length);
                    String randomMethodName = playerMethods[randomMethodIndex];
                    Method method = Player.class.getMethod(randomMethodName);
                    if( randomMethodName == "attack"){
                        player.attack(ghost);
                    }else {
                        method.invoke(player);
                    }


                    System.out.println("ghost is taking their turn");
                    int randomMethodIndex2 = random.nextInt(playerMethods.length);
                    String randomMethodName2 = ghostMethods[randomMethodIndex];
                    Method method2 = Ghost.class.getMethod(randomMethodName2);
                    if( randomMethodName2 == "ghostAttack"){
                        ghost.ghostAttack(player);
                    }else {
                        method2.invoke(ghost);
                    }

            }
        if(player.getHealth() == 0){
            System.out.println("player has died");
            System.out.println(player.health);
        }else{
            System.out.println("congratulations you've exorcised the ghost");
            System.out.println("player "+player.health);
            System.out.println("ghost "+ghost.health);
        }
    }
};
```

here is a quick dump using a python script of all the files present in the local project

```
\simple-api\ghostgame\.idea\.gitignore
\simple-api\ghostgame\.idea\compiler.xml
\simple-api\ghostgame\.idea\dbnavigator.xml
\simple-api\ghostgame\.idea\encodings.xml
\simple-api\ghostgame\.idea\jarRepositories.xml
\simple-api\ghostgame\.idea\misc.xml
\simple-api\ghostgame\.idea\workspace.xml
\simple-api\ghostgame\.idea
\simple-api\ghostgame\pom.xml
\simple-api\ghostgame\src\main\java\org\example\GameActions.java
\simple-api\ghostgame\src\main\java\org\example\Ghost.java
\simple-api\ghostgame\src\main\java\org\example\Main.java
\simple-api\ghostgame\src\main\java\org\example\Player.java
\simple-api\ghostgame\src\main\java\org\example
\simple-api\ghostgame\src\main\java\org
\simple-api\ghostgame\src\main\java
\simple-api\ghostgame\src\main\resources
\simple-api\ghostgame\src\main
\simple-api\ghostgame\src\test\java
\simple-api\ghostgame\src\test
\simple-api\ghostgame\src
\simple-api\ghostgame\target\classes\org\example\GameActions.class
\simple-api\ghostgame\target\classes\org\example\Ghost.class
\simple-api\ghostgame\target\classes\org\example\Main.class
\simple-api\ghostgame\target\classes\org\example\Player.class
\simple-api\ghostgame\target\classes\org\example
\simple-api\ghostgame\target\classes\org
\simple-api\ghostgame\target\classes
\simple-api\ghostgame\target\generated-sources\annotations
\simple-api\ghostgame\target\generated-sources
\simple-api\ghostgame\target
```

Comment: `NoSuchMethodException` means that in your ***RUNTIME*** environment the class exists but does not have that method.  You may have recompiled your code but not deployed the `Player` class into your runtime location.  We'd need to know how you're building and deploying your code to help further.

Comment: By the way [== is the wrong way to compare Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839).

Comment: When you call `Class.getMethod` you also need to give the types of the parameters the method takes.

Comment: thanks @JimGarrison I have all the classes in the same package and I'm using maven as the build env by default, I'm just debugging this locally at the moment

maybe I need to delete some folder specific to maven related to a prior build?

Comment: @JimGarrison What you describe is a `NoSuchMethodError`. The `NoSuchMethodException` that OP is getting occurs when using reflection and asking for non-existant methods. Here, the correct answer is that OP needs an explanation about how the parameter types are an intrinsic part of a method's identity in java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of calling a method, showing what happens when the parameters to `getMethod` aren't specified.

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class clazz = Player.class;
        Method defend = clazz.getMethod("defend");
        Method attack = clazz.getMethod("attack", String.class);
        Player player = new Player();
        defend.invoke(player);
        attack.invoke(player, "Ghost");
        attack = clazz.getMethod("attack"); // throws
    }

}

class Player {
    public void attack(String thing) {
        System.out.println("Attacking " + thing);
    }
    public void defend() {
        System.out.println("Defending");
    }
}
```

`defend` has no parameters, so a simple `getMethod("defend")` works, but to get `attack` you need to specify the "signature" of the method, which includes the name *and* the parameter types.

The return type of the method is *not* part of the signature, which is why a class can't have two methods with the same name and parameter types *even when* the return type is different, so you don't need to give the return type when you call `getMethod`.

Comment: right @tgdavies that's why i'm creating an explicit condition for player.attack() since it has a parameter and I am passing that parameter in ```  Method method = Player.class.getMethod(randomMethodName);
                    if( randomMethodName == "attack"){
                        player.attack(ghost);
                    }else {
                        method.invoke(player);
                    }```
that's why I'm stumped as to why I'm still getting the error

Comment: See my first comment -- you can't use `==` for `String` comparisons. Use `equals()`.

Comment: But your `getMethod` call will still throw an exception, because you are specifying a method signature that doesn't exist.

Comment: ahhhh the condition is evaluating to false I see let me play with that

Comment: I understand now, here's a quick fix I'm sure I could condense this but I'll come back to that in a bit thanks! @tgdavis looks like it works now

```
  if( randomMethodName.equals("attack")) {
                        Method method = Player.class.getMethod(randomMethodName, Ghost.class);
                        method.invoke(player, ghost);
                    }else{
                        Method method = Player.class.getMethod(randomMethodName);
                        method.invoke(player);
                    }
```

Comment: That should work.

Comment: @monsterpiece Why not just run `if (randomMethodName.equals("attack")) player.attack(ghost);`? Reflection with hardcoded strings is pretty much always wrong.